# divide matching columns on each other

Tags: r

I have a matrix with matched columns (e.g 124G and 124R) I would like to divide the matched columns on each other. The columns are not sorted based on the matching IDs like below. Could anyone suggest a function to do this?

```
                            124G      124R      126R      126G       26R       26G      243G…
hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-1 16659.1964 46129.599 53180.211 37259.453 61108.754 77946.898 87433.948
hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-2 16662.0615 46105.731 53185.511 37191.243 61115.984 77913.992 87379.138
hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-3 16639.4316 45986.194 53043.683 37157.778 60889.781 77855.132 87213.507
hsa-let-7b-5p|hsa-let-7b    8046.0040 16460.859 17660.545 20728.696 25369.899 26558.286 27932.843
hsa-let-7c-5p|hsa-let-7c     495.3461  1143.432  4671.550  1563.926  2078.405  4993.391  3479.066
hsa-let-7d-5p|hsa-let-7d    1682.8678  3879.721  4858.802  3062.387  4577.366  8218.718  7966.320
```

Comment: Have a doubt.  Do you have non-matching columns and if so how do you want to deal with that.  In the example, you have 243G without a matching one (in the solution I posted, I made up a matching column).  Also, it is not clear whether you need to divide the `G` column by `R` or viceversa.

Comment: I used `mixedorder` as it will also `sort` the column names not only within pairs but between pairs also.  From the example `mixedsort(colnames(m1))#
[1] "26G"  "26R"  "124G" "124R" "126G" "126R" "243G" "243R"` and just using `sort` i.e.  `sort(colnames(m1))#
[1] "124G" "124R" "126G" "126R" "243G" "243R" "26G"  "26R" `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base solution, nothing special here. We sort the columns, given that they all have a match - they will automatically line up to G and then the R counterpart. Then we grep all colnames with G, then R, then we divide them by each other.

```
m1 <- m1[sort(colnames(m1)]
m1_g <- m1[,grep("G",colnames(m1))]
m1_r <- m1[,grep("R",colnames(m1))]
m1_new <- m1_g/m1_r
m1_new

                                124G      126G      26G      243G
hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-1 0.3611390 0.7006263 1.275544 1.0606547
hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-2 0.3613881 0.6992740 1.274855 1.0362319
hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-3 0.3618354 0.7005128 1.278624 1.0337772
hsa-let-7b-5p|hsa-let-7b   0.4887961 1.1737291 1.046842 0.9823457
hsa-let-7c-5p|hsa-let-7c   0.4332099 0.3347767 2.402511 1.0131058
hsa-let-7d-5p|hsa-let-7d   0.4337600 0.6302761 1.795513 1.0817382
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 sapply(split(colnames(m1),sub('[^0-9]+', '', colnames(m1))), function(x) {
              x1 <- m1[,sort(x)]
               x1[,1]/x1[,2]})


#                              124       126       243       26
#hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-1 0.3611390 0.7006263 1.0606547 1.275544
#hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-2 0.3613881 0.6992740 1.0362319 1.274855
#hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-3 0.3618354 0.7005128 1.0337772 1.278624
#hsa-let-7b-5p|hsa-let-7b   0.4887961 1.1737291 0.9823457 1.046842
#hsa-let-7c-5p|hsa-let-7c   0.4332099 0.3347767 1.0131058 2.402511
#hsa-let-7d-5p|hsa-let-7d   0.4337600 0.6302761 1.0817382 1.795513
```

Or

```
library(gtools)
indx <- mixedorder(colnames(m1))
m2 <- m1[,indx]
m2[,c(TRUE,FALSE)]/m2[,c(FALSE,TRUE)]
#                               26G      124G      126G      243G
#hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-1 1.275544 0.3611390 0.7006263 1.0606547
#hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-2 1.274855 0.3613881 0.6992740 1.0362319
#hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-3 1.278624 0.3618354 0.7005128 1.0337772
#hsa-let-7b-5p|hsa-let-7b   1.046842 0.4887961 1.1737291 0.9823457
#hsa-let-7c-5p|hsa-let-7c   2.402511 0.4332099 0.3347767 1.0131058
#hsa-let-7d-5p|hsa-let-7d   1.795513 0.4337600 0.6302761 1.0817382
```

Or the above can be written as

```
 m2[,seq(1, ncol(m2), 2)]/m2[, seq(2, ncol(m2), 2)]
```

#### data

```
m1 <-  structure(c(16659.1964, 16662.0615, 16639.4316, 8046.004, 495.3461, 
1682.8678, 46129.599, 46105.731, 45986.194, 16460.859, 1143.432, 
3879.721, 53180.211, 53185.511, 53043.683, 17660.545, 4671.55, 
4858.802, 37259.453, 37191.243, 37157.778, 20728.696, 1563.926, 
3062.387, 61108.754, 61115.984, 60889.781, 25369.899, 2078.405, 
4577.366, 77946.898, 77913.992, 77855.132, 26558.286, 4993.391, 
8218.718, 87433.948, 87379.138, 87213.507, 27932.843, 3479.066, 
7966.32, 82433.94, 84323.92, 84363.93, 28434.84, 3434.06, 7364.37
), .Dim = c(6L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-1", 
"hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-2", "hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-3",
 "hsa-let-7b-5p|hsa-let-7b", 
"hsa-let-7c-5p|hsa-let-7c", "hsa-let-7d-5p|hsa-let-7d"), c("124G", 
"124R", "126R", "126G", "26R", "26G", "243G", "243R")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another idea reshaping your data in a tidy format. It accounts for non-matching columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

as.data.frame(m2) %>% 
  add_rownames("id") %>%
  gather(key, value, -id) %>% 
  extract(key, into = c("number", "letter"), "([0-9]+)([A-Z]+)") %>%
  arrange(id, number, letter) %>%
  group_by(id, number) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value / lead(value), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  spread(number, value)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
#
#                          id       124       126 243       26
#1 hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-1 0.3611390 0.7006263   0 1.275544
#2 hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-2 0.3613881 0.6992740   0 1.274855
#3 hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-3 0.3618354 0.7005128   0 1.278624
#4   hsa-let-7b-5p|hsa-let-7b 0.4887961 1.1737291   0 1.046842
#5   hsa-let-7c-5p|hsa-let-7c 0.4332099 0.3347767   0 2.402511
#6   hsa-let-7d-5p|hsa-let-7d 0.4337600 0.6302761   0 1.795513
```

**Note**: This will divide `G` by `R` (alphabetical order) for all matching columns and return `0` for non-matching ones (you could easily replace them by `NA` if needed). If you want to divide `R` by `G`, use `lag()` instead of `lead()`

---

**Data**

```
m2 <- structure(c(16659.1964, 16662.0615, 16639.4316, 8046.004, 495.3461, 
1682.8678, 46129.599, 46105.731, 45986.194, 16460.859, 1143.432, 
3879.721, 53180.211, 53185.511, 53043.683, 17660.545, 4671.55, 
4858.802, 37259.453, 37191.243, 37157.778, 20728.696, 1563.926, 
3062.387, 61108.754, 61115.984, 60889.781, 25369.899, 2078.405, 
4577.366, 77946.898, 77913.992, 77855.132, 26558.286, 4993.391, 
8218.718, 87433.948, 87379.138, 87213.507, 27932.843, 3479.066, 
7966.32), .Dim = 6:7, .Dimnames = list(c("hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-1", 
"hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-2", "hsa-let-7a-5p|hsa-let-7a-3", 
"hsa-let-7b-5p|hsa-let-7b", 
"hsa-let-7c-5p|hsa-let-7c", "hsa-let-7d-5p|hsa-let-7d"), c("124G", 
"124R", "126R", "126G", "26R", "26G", "243G")))
```